# JS Syntax Error Message

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, syntax-error, dreamweaver

I have a JS doc connected to an HTML doc. Whenever I see my code, it says there is an error on this line by saying    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input  . Nothing else is wrong and this looks fine to me.

```
if (ansA === "3") {alert("YAY");}
```

Comment: the issue may not be with this snippet

Comment: Since you are using dreamweaver, I doubt if there are some hidden string

Comment: the error could be on a previous line. what do you have before this?